# Flutter - Add GridView without specify a container height

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I'm having troubles setting a `GridView` that should show some buttons to allow user to choose an hour to book.
This is my `GridView` code:

```
GridView.count(
    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 16.0,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: <Widget>[
        ...currentVariations.map((element) {
            return HourButton(
                firstRow: 'ore',
                secondRow: element.orario,
                active: element.id == variationId,
                onPressed: (){}
             );
        }).toList()                              
    ],
 )
```

My screen has a `CustomScrollView` with `SliverAppBar` and a `SliverList` in which I have a `SliverChildListDelegate` that contains a Column with all my widgets.

The problem is that if I add the GridView as above it do not appear on screen so to make it visibile I have added this:

```
Container(
    height: 120,
    child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
      context: context,
      removeTop: true,
      child: GridView.count(
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 16.0,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[
          ...currentVariations.map((element) {
            return HourButton(
              firstRow: 'ore',
              secondRow: element.orario,
              active: element.id == variationId,
              onPressed: (){},
            );
          }).toList()
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

With the `Container` and `MediaQuery.removePadding` it shows but in this way I need to set the `Container` height to see the list.

This is the result:

[image]

How can I make the container height automatic?

Comment: Try setting shrinkwrap = true property of grid view. Also set scroll physics as never scrollable in grid view if it's a child of some other scroll view.

Comment: `shrinkWrap: true` was exactly what I needed, it works! `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` was already set